# I Want to create a Contact form with User profile name auto input (Dynamic Text)

Tags: php, jquery, forms, dynamic, contacts

I Want to create a Contact form in a custom web software (Not made by me but client) now he wants a extra class signup form with User profile name auto input (Dynamic Text). Is there a way todo in PHP. 
Actually Codes made by others are a little problem to me.

If someone could tell me how can i call for name value from this code i will appreciate it

```
  <a class="dropdown-toggle profile-pic" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#"> <img src="<?php echo $this->crud_model->get_image_url($this->session->userdata('login_type'), $this->session->userdata('login_user_id'));?>" alt="user-img" width="36" class="img-circle"><b class="hidden-xs"><?php
                    echo $this->db->get_where($this->session->userdata('login_type'), array(
                    $this->session->userdata('login_type') . '_id' => $this->session->userdata('login_user_id')))->row()->name;?></b> </a>
```

Thanks

Comment: Yes, there is a way to perform logic and produce results in PHP.  If you think code written by others is difficult to understand and successfully modify, imagine asking us to understand and successfully modify code we can't even see.

Comment: What is it you're actually asking here? I mean, you can do almost anything with most back end languages and some creativity.

Comment: Dear friends, I am new to PHP i don't know much. So if you guys can give a idea how would the form just get the profile name data on the name field i would really appreciate it

Comment: SO isn't a free coding service, nor is it a forum for discussing theoretical solutions. SO is a Q&A for developers when they run into specific issues with their existing code. It's your job to write your code and when you run in to some issue which you can't solve yourself (after doing proper research), you need to show us what you've tried, let us know what the expected outcome is and what actually happens.

Comment: @TechincalHacks: You'd start with some introductory tutorials on PHP to get a basic idea of what it is and how it works.  Then you'd take the existing code and attempt to modify it to perform the new task.  This would likely involve (A) getting the value from wherever you'd get it (database, for example) and (B) outputting the value to the page where you want to put it.  These concepts are covered by just about any PHP tutorial.

Comment: @David can you link please one tutorial to get value and then output anywhere else please

Comment: @TechincalHacks: Sure, here you go: https://www.google.com/search?q=php+tutorial

Comment: Asking for tutorials or other off site resources are off topic for SO. You have Google and I bet you can find many many tutorials about most things PHP. After all, it is one of the most common languages.

Comment: Your profile reads as: *"Web Developer"*. Do you understand what that term means? It means that you "develop" web sites and for the most part, everything that runs not only as client-side to see but in the backend where all the magic happens. You as a web developer, shouldn't be relying on others to do the work for you, be it code, and researching this. By all means, this isn't meant to insult you, but to inform you what a web developer (really) is and does.

Comment: if someone could atleast tell me how toget name value from this

      <a class="dropdown-toggle profile-pic" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#"> <img src="<?php echo $this->crud_model->get_image_url($this->session->userdata('login_type'), $this->session->userdata('login_user_id'));?>" alt="user-img" width="36" class="img-circle"><b class="hidden-xs"><?php
                        echo $this->db->get_where($this->session->userdata('login_type'), array(
                        $this->session->userdata('login_type') . '_id' => $this->session->userdata('login_user_id')))->row()->name;?></b> </a>

Comment: By the way; you want us to guide/help you with something we know nothing about someone else's software, nor have you left any code to work from. If this is actual software, then this isn't the place to get help. We deal with code that interacts with language that is compatible with what you're wanting to use.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Sorry i missed the code but had upadted it now. I am learning php i want to know how to call for the profile name value as this code is calling to displaying it in header. and i want to display it in a form text field

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Guys for all the Moral Support because without you guys i would't have researched this much. Thanks again

solved it with:

```
<?php echo $_SESSION['name']; ?>
```

now can anybody tell me how can i include in my form text field. Please